# C++ initialization of reference variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I spotted a "mistake" in my code today... But I'm not sure if the "mistake" actually changes the resulting compiled code.

Consider initialization of the following reference to a `double`, `x`.

```
double &x{*_data->x_double}; // x_double is a member variable of the struct
                             // _data, it is a pointer to another double

// eg, I have this somewhere else...
struct data
{
    double *x_double;
};

data *_data = new data; // edit: duh, this has to be a pointer...

double another_x = 10.0;
_data->x_double = &another_x; // edit: pointer here too!
```

However I made the following "mistake"... (notice the extra `=` sign)

```
double &x={*_data->x_double};
```

This code is a minimal example copied from my actual code, in which I don't have references to doubles, but references to large objects such as `std::vector`'s.

The reason for the reference variables is that they are used in an algorithm, and the variable names are *very* long, so I create shorted aliases for those variables using references. Hope it makes sense why I did that...

So, I've "corrected" the "mistake" but has my output compiled code actually changed?

Comment: Just look at the rules of [reference initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization).

Comment: @GillBates So, the output code is the same, right?

Comment: @user3728501 Yes, it is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

They're both [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). For your cases:

```
double &x={*_data->x_double};
```

Is :

> 6) initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list after an
>   equals sign

And

```
double &x{*_data->x_double};
```

Is :

> 1) initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list (that
>   is, a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested
>   braced-init-lists)

Their effects are in this case exactly the same.